# How to install Gnumeric on Redhat server?

Tags: linux, server, redhat

I want to convert .xlsx file to .csv files. if i try to install gnumeric from repository it says package not found. so suggest me how to install or else suggest me alternative tools. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download fedora 21 rpms for gnumeric and goffice.

ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/gnumeric-1.12.18-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/goffice-0.10.18-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

Install them both simultaneousely with:

```
rpm -Uvh gnumeric-1.12.18-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm goffice-0.10.18-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```